# Error when Compiling Linux Kernel for Android 11 (R) Beta version 1 with clang-r383902

Tags: linux-kernel, clang, cross-compiling, beta, android-11

I am using an Ubuntu 20.04 machine with the newest version of platform-tools installed and (I believe) all necessary dependencies.

I created a new directory ~/beta1-kernel-coral and within this directory I cloned the kernel:

`git clone -b android-msm-coral-4.14-r-beta-1 https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/`

I noticed the clang version used was clang-r383902. I downloaded [this directory](https://github.com/crdroidandroid/android_prebuilts_clang_host_linux-x86_clang-6443078) and extracted it so that I had two separate directories within ~/beta1-kernel-coral: msm and clang-r383902.

From within ~/beta1-kernel-coral/msm, I ran two commands:

```
make floral_defconfig
make menuconfig
```

Next, using [Nathan Chance's guide from Github](https://github.com/nathanchance/android-kernel-clang), I ran the following command:

`PATH="/home/jherwig/beta1-kernel-coral/clang-r383902/android_prebuilts_clang_host_linux-x86_clang-6443078-10.0/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:${PATH}" make -j$(nproc --all) ARCH=arm64 CC=clang CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android- CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32=arm-linux-androideabi-`

The kernel began compiling until I received the following output:

https://pastebin.com/61pkd6uf

In Nathan's guide, he intructs to use:

`PATH="<path to clang folder>/bin:<path to 64-bit gcc folder>/bin:<path to 32-bit gcc folder>/bin:${PATH}" \ ...`

Since I installed gcc-multilib, I thought `<path to 64-bit gcc folder>` and `<path to 32-bit gcc folder>` would be in /usr/bin. When I type `which gcc` in terminal I get /usr/bin/gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAF kernels are NOT mainline kernels and you cannot compile them as such. You must run make distclean and specify an out directory for each make command, including the defconfig

Example:
make O=out

If you do not specify O=out for each make command you'll hit these errors
The value assigned to O can be anything, doesn't have to be out but you cannot build the kernel in the same directory as the source

Change this:

make floral_defconfig

make menuconfig

To this:

make floral_defconfig O=out

make menuconfig O=out

The build it with:

make O=out

Remember to make distclean in the source directory first

Comment: Thank you for responding!! This is excellent info that will hopefully help future users as well.

Comment: The build guide has slightly changed for android 12. You need to use make O=out LLVM=1 and if the relevant change lands, LLVM_IAS=1 as well